# Quickly processing long lists using SequencePosition

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, functional-style, code-review

**Overview**
SequencePosition does exactly what I need; however, it seems to be very slow for long lists. Is there an input option that would allow it to process faster? Or, perhaps an alternative function to use?    If not, I have written a simple code to perform this task,any recommendation to improve this code?

**Details**
In this case I have a long list with 0s and 1s.  I want to make a list of position pairs indicating the  beginning and end of each sequence of 1s within the list.

For example, for the list:  {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
the list of position pairs would be: {{2,3},{5,7}, {10,11}}.

**Example** Processing with SequencePosition -- base cases, possible combinations of where lists of 1s start and stop.

```
listA = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
listB = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
listC = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
listD = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
listE = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
listF = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
listAll  = {listA, listB, listC, listD, listE, listF};


vPosAll = 
  SequencePosition[#, {Repeated[1]}, Overlaps -> False] & /@ listAll;
Framed[TableForm[#]] & /@ vPosAll

(*results are as expected*)
```

Processing with SequencePosition -- long list. Haven't seen this return a result

```
listLong = RandomInteger[1, 300000];
{timeLong, vPosLong } = 
 Timing[SequencePosition[listLong, {Repeated[1]}, Overlaps -> False]]

(*takes a long time to process*)
```

**Alternative**
Write a function to identify the beginning and end of each list of 1s within the long list.

```
find01Lists[vIn_] := Module[{v01, v10
   , has1Q, firstIs1, lastIs1, n01, n10},
  
  (*catch case when the list does not contain a 1*)
  has1Q = First@FirstPosition[#, 1, {-1}] > 0 & @ vIn;
  If[! has1Q, Return[{-1, -1}]];
  
  (*find the positions where the sequence begins*)
  v01 = SequencePosition[vIn, {0, 1}, Overlaps -> False];
  (*find the positions where the sequence end*)
  v10 = SequencePosition[vIn, {1, 0}, Overlaps -> False];
  
  (*adjust lists, if the sequence begins or ends at the edge*)
  {firstIs1, lastIs1} = {MatchQ[First@#, 1], MatchQ[Last@#, 1]} & @ 
    vIn;
  If[firstIs1, PrependTo[v01, {1, 1}]];
  If[lastIs1, AppendTo[v10, {Length@testList, Length@testList}]];
  
  (*check for errors: length of the lists should be the same*)
  If[ Length@v01 != Length@v10, Return[{-1, -1}]];
  
  (*return results*)
  Table[{Last@v01[[i]], First@v10[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@v01}]
  ]
```

Apply the function to the example lists

```
(*test with the examples*)
Framed[{Framed@
     TableForm[{Prepend[Range@Length@#, "index:"], 
       Prepend[#, "data:"]}], find01Lists[#]}] & /@ listAll

(*results are as expected*)
```

Apply the function to a long list

```
(*test with a long list*)
longList = RandomInteger[1, 300000];
{timeLongList, posLongList} = Timing[find01Lists[listLong]];
timeLongList
(*reports about 0.1 seconds of processing time*)

(*check first 25 results -- should only see 1 in the extracted lists*)
listLong[[First@# ;; Last@#]] & /@ Take[posLongList, 25]  // TableForm

(*results as expected*)
```

**Question**
Is there a way to achieve this result more elegantly with built in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v={0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0};
Transpose[Lookup[PositionIndex@Differences@Join[{0},v,{0}],{1,-1},{}]-{0,1}]

(*{{2, 3}, {5, 7}, {10, 11}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks!   this is what I was looking for.  It handles all special cases and on my system it can process a list with a million entries in less than 0.05 seconds.